# No output from GTX 1050

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, xorg, games

I have a PC with Ryzen 5 2400G and GTX 1050. Since it has an integrated GPU I enabled it for use with normal applications, while using the GTX 1050 for games. In Windows, I can get output from both of the GPUs. But in Ubuntu, I am only getting a signal from the integrated GPU. Due to this, I won't be able to change display settings in the NVIDIA Xserver settings. All the drivers are installed properly and my Ubuntu 20.04 is also up to date.

Edit: This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c6)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```